# Generate Image from SVG with CSS styles

Tags: c#, image, svg

I want to render image from css styled(not inline css) svg using C#.

I tried https://svg.codeplex.com. But there were alignment and scaling issues. Really appreciate any help.

Comment: What are you trying to solve by rendering SVGs - rendering resolution independent icons or something? Would it be easier to save the SVGs as PDFs and then use a library like this? http://pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @KevinChen. What i want to do is, I use svg to draw cad like drawings in the browser. When saving, i want to render a thumbnail of the drawing. In the client side I use css.

Comment: have you tried the more recent version of the library? https://github.com/vvvv/SVG also, it may help to inline the CSS before rendering: http://www.milkshakehq.com/PreMailer.Net/

Comment: Yeah im using premailer to convert css to inline. Thnkx i'll try the latest. Earlier I had some scaling and alignment issues.